# release apk is getting reference again and again

Tags: flutter

When I run the app in debug mode, it works correctly, but when I install the release app, it works fine, but when I open the app for the second time, the app appears to be reloaded or referenced again and again.

Comment: When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      StatefulElement.state (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4999:44)
#1      Navigator.of (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:2543:47)
#2      Navigator.pushReplacement (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:2105:22)
#3      Splashservice.isLogin.<anonymous closure> (package:shridungargarh/service/splashservice.dart:15:19)
#4      SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1175:15)
#5      SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1104

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

sometime play protect issues maybe occur.
can you post mobile OS version issues.

Comment: i don't understand please tell me what should i share with you

Comment: your android mobile version or which device u tested?

Comment: android version 12 and mobile model  oppo reno 6